# setting up multiple IP addresses on one ethernet interface?

Tags: networking, ethernet, access-point, raspbian-buster

I am running Buster on a RP3B+.  It is configured as a stand-alone wifi access point running dnsmasq.  No bridging to the eth0 / Internet.  It also has a wired eth0 interface.  Everything is working correctly.

I want to allow a user to set a static IP on the eth0.  I also want to have a default IP that they can use if the mess up setting their own IP.

Traditionally this has been done with a small switch that resets the device to factory defaults.  I don't want to do that.

I want to have a fixed static default IP plus a user set static IP running on eth0.

I understand that I do have the option of allowing a user to connect through the Wifi to set the IP.  I will probably do that as well.

There are answers to this question out there but it appears many are out of date.  I specifically want a solution that is compatible with Raspbian Buster (released only a few days ago at the time of writing) configured as a simple Access Point with wired ethernet.

I have mentioned the wifi AP setup only because it is not standard and may affect the setup of the eth0 interface.  That includes installing dnsmasq.  I just want to have 2x static IP addresses assigned to the eth0 interface.

Dazz

Comment: This question makes no sense. If you are setting up an AP this normally involves implementing a DHCP server (which requires a fixed ip address). There is nothing to stop users setting a compatible static address (although why they would want to do this eludes me). PS the Raspbian Buster networking is the same as Stretch.

Comment: The wlan0 has a single static address.  dnsmasq provides dynamic IPs to connected wifi devices.  No changes needed to the wlan0 interface.  I want to add a 2nd fixed and static IP to eth0.  The 1st IP will be user set for eth0 only.  Buster networking is probably not the same as Stretch.  I have been trying for months to get an AP running on Stretch without success.  The same instructions/setup worked first time on Buster.

Comment: You could go for ethernet over USB : https://www.amazon.de/CableCreation-CD0188-USB-Kabel-schwarz-St%C3%BCck-Black-White/dp/B01FJQGCB0/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=USB&qid=1562760655&s=computers&sr=1-4

Comment: Traditionally this has been done with software proxy servers, there was never a built-in way to have 2 IPs at once. I believe what you want is to have a shellscript that checks if eth0 is up and has internet connection, and if not, "sudo ifconfig eth0 down" , set up a dynamic ip, and up again. Then would be my question, why have the user decide about his IP in the first place?

Comment: I don't think the OP wants two addresses at once - he wants DHCP to be able to allocate to the device connected to eth0 either a fixed IP address that he will define at development time, or a dynamic one. Is that the correct interpretation, @dazz?

Comment: Yes I do want to assign multiple static IP addresses to the eth0 interface.    This is not an uncommon requirement with multiple solutions. See this link for one solution:  https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-assign-multiple-ip-addresses-to-single-network-card-in-linux/   I an not asking whether it can be done.  I am asking how it should be done with the latest Raspbian version.

Comment: I found an answer at this link:  https://superuser.com/questions/1345361/multiple-static-ip-debian-9-stretch-on-one-interface   I haven't tried it yet but others have had success.